# How can I get average task completion time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 columns of dates like these:

```
DateStart                      DateFinish
2019-07-24 13:24:08.7530000    2019-07-29 12:13:00.8930000
2019-08-07 11:06:54.7540000    2019-10-02 11:59:08.2780000
```

I need to get average task completion time (hours : minutes : seconds). Avg time may be more than 23 : 59 : 59. 
For example:

```
AvgTime
48:25:12
```

I use MS SQL.

Comment: please show what have you tried

Comment: What is the calculation logic?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DateStart and DateFinish are stored as DateTime2, you can use `DATEDIFF(SECOND,DateStart, DateFinish)` to get the total number of seconds between the two dates. You can then use `AVG` on this value to get the average seconds for all records.

Then format this back into hours:minutes:seconds using a bit of maths and then converting to varchar to stick the elements together. `Right('00'+...,2)` to force leading zeros.

```
SELECT

   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), AvgSeconds / 60 / 60 )
    +':'+ right(('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AvgSeconds / 60 % 60)),2)
    +':'+ RIGHT(('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AvgSeconds % 60)),2)  AS [HHMMSS]

From
    (
       SELECT
          avg(DATEDIFF(SECOND,DateStart, DateFinish)) AS AvgSeconds
       From
          SomeTable
    ) AS T
```

If you want to include days in this, then you can just add another level.

```
SELECT
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), AvgSeconds / 60 / 60 /24)
    +':'+ right(('00'+  CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), AvgSeconds / 60 / 60 %24)), 2)
    +':'+ right(('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AvgSeconds / 60 % 60)),2)
    +':'+ RIGHT(('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), AvgSeconds % 60)),2)  AS [DDHHMMSS]
From
    (
       SELECT
          avg(DATEDIFF(SECOND,DateStart, DateFinish)) AS AvgSeconds
       FROM
          SomeTable
    ) AS T
```

Comment: Awesome!
Thank you very much!
How can I add days?

Comment: When FinishTime = 2019-09-03 and StartTime 2019-08-07

I would like to get 2019-08-07 - 2019-09-03 = 26+ days or 26 * 24 hours :)

Comment: Between 2019-08-07 00:00:00 and 2019-09-03 00:00:00 is 27 days exactly. The code above gives that already.

Comment: I can get full date when i subtract one date from another?

Comment: I think you need to expand your original question with examples of what you're wanting as an output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
Convert(varchar,[seconds]/3600/24) +':'+
Convert(varchar,([seconds]/3600)%24) +':'+
Convert(varchar,([seconds]/60)%60)+':'+
Convert(varchar,([seconds]%60)) AS [AvgTime(DDHHMMSS)]
from (
select 
Convert(varchar,AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND,DateStart,DateFinish)))
as seconds from #ras
)XX
```